# Por que utilizar um ponteiro para struct, ao invés da própria struct neste caso?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Por que, na `struct` `GERENTE` e `CLIENTE`, eu tenho que usar um ponteiro para a `struct` `PESSOA` e não a própria `struct` `PESSOA`

```
typedef struct{
    char* nome;
    int cpf;
} PESSOA;

typedef struct{
   PESSOA* pessoa;
   int valorContaCorrente;
   int valorDaDivida;
   char tipo;
} CLIENTE;

typedef struct{
   PESSOA* pessoa;
   int numClientes;
   CLIENTE* clientes[20];
} GERENTE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ter muitos motivos, inclusive vários errados. Parece ser um exercício que pede para fazer isso. Se ele pede, deveria explicar o porquê, se não explica, não é um bom exercício.

Ponteiro é uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), então o maior motivo para usar um ponteiro é porque precisa de uma indireção. Mas o motivo específico de precisar de uma indireção eu não posso responder porque não sei qual é o problema que está tentando resolver. Problemas artificiais não são bons para aprender programar.

Sem o ponteiro a estrutura usada será alocada ali mesmo, o que chamamos de *inplace*, então dentro dessa nova `struct` terá um espaço reservado para o objeto da outra `struct`. Portanto o motivo é o mesmo que usou `char *` e não `char[30]` por exemplo. O ponteiro diz que você vai alocar o objeto em outro lugar e ali só colocará o endereço desse outro lugar. Se deseja isso então ótimo, se não deseja, não tem porque fazer assim.

Obviamente que assim como se espera que aloque memória para usar em `nome`, também em algum ponto do código terá que alocar memória para `pessoa`, e claro, depois inicializar o objeto nesse local.

Eu nem posso dizer que é o certo a fazer porque todos os membros dessas estruturas parecem usar tipos errados, talvez porque a intenção seja só aprender colocar algo em C, e não programar corretamente, mas isso é outro assunto não relacionado com a pergunta em si. Treinar o erro faz a pessoa acostumar com ele.